# Base R: Plotting beyond the plotting window despite using xlim

Tags: r, plot

The question is best described by this line of code

> plot(1:100,1:100, xlim = c(0,50))

It generates the following, which has the graph going outside of the window. I don't believe I have ever experienced this before in R.

[image]

Comment: The code works as expected for my set up: x axis 0 to 50, shapes all within the plot panel.

Comment: Probably the `par`s are messed up. Use `graphics.off()` to shut down all devices, whereafter each new device will be started with default `par`s. You can store `op <- par()` and restore them later `par(op)` if you use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the expand (`xpd`) parameter is set to `NA` (by the plot function or via global setting like `par(xpd = NA)`), plot elements will extend beyond plot. Setting `par(xpd = FALSE)` restricts plotting to the plot region (inside the box - the default); setting (`xpd = TRUE`) restricts plotting to the figure region (within the margins) and `xpd = NA` allows plotting over the entire graphics device. See the `xpd` section of `?par`.

You can return to the default setting by restarting R or running the line `par(xpd = FALSE)`.

Comment: Thank you Gregor Thomas for the addition! Made me wonder how the parameter got set globally apparently without the OP's intent.